# Problema com npm install ao fazer deploy no servidor

Tags: node.js, npm, centos

Desenvolvi um site usando Vue e Node, ambos totalmente funcionais na minha maquina, ao hospedar o backend no servidor web (utilizei o kings host) e tentar executar o npm install para instalar as dependências deu o seguinte erro: "node-gyp error: not found: make"
O SO do servidor é centOS.
Solicitei que o serviço tecnico verificasse a instalação do make, mas eles verificaram que o mesmo se encontra instalado.
Não consigo encontrar nenhuma resposta satisfatória para a questão.

Comment: Talvez ajude-o: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31032594/9101590

Comment: Eu não sei bem oque aconteceu, mas o problema foi solucionado quando gerei novamente o package.json nas configurações padrão "npm init -y", copiei as dependências e dei um "npm i" pra gerar o package-lock.json e substitui ambos nos servidor, quando rodei novamente o "npm i" no ssh rodou tudo certo. Mas obrigado pela ajuda!